# Caml Query Filter SharePoint 2013 Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, client-object-model

Hi I'm in need of some help with a caml query. I have 1 column in my list, that have 3 different choice.

I want to query out items if the choice is equal to YES

This is my code:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
enter code hered

var web = context.get_web(); 
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("MyList");  

var viewXml = String.format(
"<View>" +
"<Query>" +
"<Where>" +
"<Eq>" +
"<FieldRef Name='MyChoiceField' />" +
"<Value Type='Choice'>YES</Value>" +
"</Eq>" +
"</Where>" +
"</Query>" +
"</View>");

var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
query.set_viewXml(viewXml);
this.items = list.getItems(query);
```

The rest of the code works except the query

Comment: Is it a typo, there is no + after "</Where>"

Comment: In my environment there is a +, i missed it here

Comment: what is the actual name of the field. Perhaps you may not be using the internal name of the field.

Comment: Updated it as the answer so that it can be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Check the internal name of the field. The CAML query needs the internal name of the field.